# If I can rewrite an inequality $f(x,y)> g(x,y)$ as $ h(x,y)>k(x,y)$, does that mean $f(x,y)>g(x,y)$ IFF $h(x,y)>k(x,y)$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

If I can rewrite an inequality $f(x,y)> g(x,y)$ as $ h(x,y)>k(x,y)$, does that mean $f(x,y)>g(x,y)$ If and only if $h(x,y)>k(x,y)$?

---

My reasoning/difficulty:

Suppose I can rewrite $f(x,y)>g(x,y)$ as $h(x,y)>k(x,y)$. Then $f(x,y)>g(x,y) \implies h(x,y) > k(x,y)$ **(i.e. $h(x,y)>k(x,y)$ is necessary for $f(x,y)>g(x,y)$)**.

Then, if i reverse the steps I should be able to show the opposite direction -- that $h(x,y)>k(x,y)$ is sufficient for $f(x,y)>g(x,y)$)

However, **is it always possible to reverse the steps?** Intuitively I feel like it should be.

Also, what method could be used to prove such a statement (it seems to me like it would be a proof showing that **any** possible transformation of the original inequality is reversible, but how can I prove that **any** transformation is reversible? It seems impossible to be sure there is not some transformation being overlooked?)

Edit:

- I have tried to elaborate on what I mean by "re-write" in the comments.
- I think for the result to have a shot at being true we need to assume that $f(x,y)\neq 0$ and $g(x,y)\neq 0$ (and maybe also for $h(x,y)$ and $k(x,y)$?). Thanks for the answer that points this out.

Edit 2: Perhaps a simple and more concrete version of the question:

> Consider the inequality $2x^2y + 3y^2 > xy +5$ and suppose that it holds.
>
> This inequality implies (assuming $y\neq 0$) that $2x^2 - x > -3y +
> > \frac{5}{y}$
>
> Therefore, $2x^2 - x > -3y + \frac{5}{y}$ **if** $2x^2y + 3y^2 > xy +5$
>
> **Restated question**: Since I obtained $2x^2y + 3y^2 > xy +5$ from $2x^2 - x > -3y + \frac{5}{y}$, can i automatically say that  $2x^2 - x > -3y + \frac{5}{y}$ **only if** $2x^2y + 3y^2 > xy +5$,

Comment: What does "rewrite" mean here?

Comment: @"rewrite" means if I can take some inequality and re-arrange terms to obtain a different inequality (using operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and where we are not multiplying/dividing by 0, and if we multiply/divide by a negative number we change the sign of the inequality).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So for example, I can "rewrite" $2x^2y + 3y^2 > xy +5$ as $2x^2 - x > -3y + \frac{5}{y}$ as long as $y=0$ is not in the domain

Comment: @user106860: If $y$ is smaller than $0$, then you *cannot* "rewrite" $2x^2y+3y^2\gt xy+5$ as $2x^2-x\gt -3y+\frac 5y$.

Comment: @mathlove Ah, you're right. If we restrict to $y>0$ though, does being able to re-write $2x^2y+3y^2\gt xy+5$ as $2x^2-x\gt -3y+\frac 5y$ mean $2x^2y+3y^2\gt xy+5$ IF and ONLY IF $2x^2-x\gt -3y+\frac 5y$?

Comment: @user106860: Yes, when $y\gt 0$, the two inequalities are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewritten inequality is obtained from the initial by elementary steps, “using operations like addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and where we are not multiplying/dividing by 0, and if we multiply/divide by a negative number we change the sign of the inequality”. So we have to check when such an operation transforms an inequality to an equivalent inequality. This can be understood studying [basic properties of inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Properties). Below I briefly list some elementary equivalent transformations of inequalities.

$f<g$ iff $f+t<g+t$ for each real $t$ and each real $f$ and $g$.

$f<g$ iff $tf<tg$ for each positive real $t$ and each real $f$ and $g$.

$f<g$ iff $tf>tg$ for each negative real $t$ and each real $f$ and $g$.

$f<g$ iff $\exp(f)<\exp(g)$ for each real $f$ and $g$.

$f<g$ iff $\ln(f)<\ln(g)$ for each positive real $f$ and $g$.

Comment: The iff is what I was wondering about. The wikipedia seems to often state the properties only using an "if" statement though? For example, "For any real numbers $a, b, c$
If $a ≤ b$, then $a + c ≤ b + c$ and $a − c ≤ b − c$.
If $ a ≥ b$, then $a + c ≥ b + c$ and $a − c ≥ b − c$.". I guess I am confused why  you state it with an IFF (which I agree with), whereas I've seen it in other places (like the WIKI) with if statements. (Maybe the only if is so elementary that they don't both stating it? Or perhaps I am just misunderstanding something)

Comment: @user106860 I guess other places provide sufficient conditions for validity of transformations, for instance, “if $a\le  b$ then $a + c\le b + c $”. But our case is about their equivalence, so I cared about “iff”. The “only if” its part usually is “if” part for the transformed inequality. For instance, $a+c\le b+c$ implies $a=(a+c)-c\le (b+c)-c=b$, so $a\le  b$ iff $a + c\le b + c $.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, No. For example $x>0$ can we rewritten as $x^2>0$.Clearly the if and only if does not follow

Comment: @user106860 how do you "rewrite" when multiplying by functions that change sign?